# SET NOCOUNT ON Donde usar? Otro método para la optimización de SP's - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimización

estoy aprendiendo y manejando un poco el tema de la optimizacion de consultas si alguien me puede retroalimentar

Se que `SET NOCOUNT ON;` funciona a modo de optimizar y acelerar una consulta dentro del SQL, lo que quiero saber es donde comenzar a ponerlo, si despues de Declarar variables, antes, antes del Select

Y que otros metodos hay para una mejor optimizacion de consultas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El `SET NOCOUNT ON` como lo dice la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-nocount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), hace que no se muestre el total de filas afectadas en sentencias `SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`. Dependiendo de la lógica del script o stored procedure, el ocultar este mensaje puede redundar en una mejora de performance, tal como se menciona:

> For stored procedures that contain several statements that do not
> return much actual data, or for procedures that contain Transact-SQL
> loops, setting SET NOCOUNT to ON can provide a significant performance
> boost, because network traffic is greatly reduced.

Entendamos que, aunque pequeño, éste es un mensaje que viaja por la red y llega al cliente incluso si no hubiera datos que se retornen, sin duda puede haber un escenario dónde esto sea significativo, aunque lo más probable que en estos casos, se requiera más bien una optimización en la lógica más que en este detalle.

Pero también hay hay otros sentidos para esto:

1. Meramente estético: Cuando un stored procedure que no retorna datos simplemente realiza actualizaciones y otras operaciones, puede quedar más "estético" y tal vez más lógico el no mostrar las cantidades de filas afectadas, hay que tener en cuenta que sino este datos se mostraría por cada clausula antes mencionada.
2. Consistente con la lógica del Script/Sp o necesario técnicamente: El caso de un stored procedure que retorna un recorset de datos, pero en el medio realiza múltiples sentencias SQL, en este caso, es conveniente usar el `SET NOCOUNT ON` para "ocultar" esta salida para todas las sentencias intermedias y habilitar la misma con el `SET NOCOUNT OFF` únicamente con el `SELECT` final, de esta forma, las filas obtenidas  serán consistentes con la información de filas afectadas. Necesario técnicamente: me he encontrado alguna vez con ciertos clientes que requieren de esta información y que particularmente sea consistente con las filas recibidas, esto es por que esta sentencia previene el envío del mensaje DONE_IN_PROC que marca al cliente la finalización del stored procedure y que alguna herramienta puede eventualmente esperar, por lo cual controlar dónde se muestra este mensaje puede ser un requerimiento técnico.

Answer (score 1):

`SET NOCOUNT ON` no es un método para optimizar y acelerar una consulta. Lo que hace es evitar que se muestren mensajes de la cantidad de filas afectadas. Esto se hace para evitar mensajes que no son necesarios al realizar las consultas desde una aplicación.

Al ser una instrucción que define como se comportará el código dentro de la sesión, debe ser la primer instrucción que se utilice.

Comment: La documentación indica que puede proporcionar un aumento de desempeño significativo en procedimientos con varias sentencias o con ciclos.